# Ableton Alternatives?

Tags: sound, playonlinux, ubuntu-studio, midi

I've tried and failed using PlayOnLinux to get Ableton Live to run, and I am aware that there are tools to record and mix music already existing for Linux.  What I need, however, is access to very high-quality sampled instruments that Ableton comes with (i.e. the entire orchestra that Ableton Live comes with).  Is there anything on Linux that has high-quality orchestral MIDI OR is there a way to buy such instruments separately and hook them up to a Linux DAW?

Comment: There are many DAWs, MIDI sequencers and Virtual Instruments available for Linux. There is also a lot of free and commercial software that works on many Operating Systems, or can be used in Linux. There are many sites online that already list software available or have guides and tutorials for using them

Comment: have you tried **Traktion** already, i have and i play the guitar and with a good sound card, i am able to record what i  play. **Traktion** is actually free for Linux

Answer (score 0):

[Bitwig studio](https://www.bitwig.com/en/bitwig-studio.html) runs on Linux, OSX and windows. It's similar to Ableton. I remember being told rumors prior to it's first release that some of the dev team are(were?) former Ableton developers.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using [Reaper](https://www.reaper.fm/) on Linux and is pretty solid and stable. Also the cost is not so much so you could give it a tried. It has a lot of plugins by default, and is compatible with LV2 and Linux VST plugins.